# Use requests to extract html content with list in html set to a specific value

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am doing a project in scraping the below site

```
http://www.akvariefisk.dk/market/
```

Upon entering this site, prior obtaining data from it, I want to set the list seen in the below source code to a specific value - in this current case, it is value 1.

Source code from html

```
> <form method="post" name="frm" id="frm">
>     <select name="area" onchange="frm.submit();">
>     <option value="99" selected="">Alle
>     </option><option value="0">Udlandet
>     </option><option value="1">Storkøbenhavn
>     </option><option value="3">Nordsjælland    
>     </option><option value="4">Øvrige sjælland
>     </option><option value="11">Hele Sjælland
>     </option><option value="2">Bornholm
>     </option><option value="5">Fyn
>     </option><option value="6">Sønderjylland
>     </option><option value="7">Midt- &amp; vestjylland
>     </option><option value="8">Østjylland
>     </option><option value="9">Nordjylland
>     </option><option value="10">Hele Jylland
```

My current code look like below, and how can I specify the value above first, prior calling the requests.get?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.akvariefisk.dk/market/"
#obtain data
req = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: You should take a look at [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Network tab in the Inspector in Google Chrome, you'll see that when you select the option 1 "Stork...", the website sends a POST request to the web server and gets an HTML code of the page as the response.

So just send a POST request with data:

```
r = requests.post('http://www.akvariefisk.dk/market/', {'area': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is only used for scraping the website, not changing it. There are 2 options:

- You can scrape the site for the options and get the value of the first option, and then send a request (probably POST request), similar to one that this form sends. If you want to see which request you should use and which params you should send, just look at the `inputs` tags or use the `Chrome DevTools` to sniff on the requests (press F12 and go to the `network` section).
- You can simulate web browser with the [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Hope this was helpful :)